# Contact Form 7 two columns

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

Today I made a contact form but it has many elements. So, I decided to make it in two columns. But it is not working. Here is my code:

```
<div class="kolumny">
<div class="polowa">
<p>Nazwa Firmy (wymagane)<br />
    [text* your-company class:required] </p>

<p>Osoba Kontaktowa<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Numer Telefonu<br />
    [number* your-number min:5 max:15 step:3 class:required "40"] </p>

<p>Adres email (wymagane)<br />
    [email* your-email class:required] </p>

<p>Pracowników na umowę o pracę<br />
    [select* your-employees include_blank "0" "1-5" "6-20" "21-50" "powyżej 50"] </p>

<p>Pracowników na umowę zlecenie/dzieło<br />
    [select* your-employees1 include_blank "0" "1-5" "6-20" "21-50" "powyżej 50" </p>
</div>

<div class="polowa2">
<p>Forma prawna (wymagane)<br />
    [select* your-prawna include_blank "os. fizyczna" "sp. cywilna" "sp. jawna" "sp. z o.o." "sp. Akcyjna" "inna" "planuję dopiero rozpocząć działalność" class:required] </p>

<p>Forma księgowości (wymagane)<br />
    [select* your-prawna include_blank "pełna księgowość" "podatkowa księga PiR" "ryczałt ewidencjonowany" "karta podatkowa" "planuję dopiero rozpocząć działalność" class:required] </p>

<p>Przedmiot działalności<br />
    [text* your-work] </p>

<p>Vatowiec (wymagane)<br />
    [checkbox* your-vat exclusive "tak" "nie"]</p>

<p>Dokumentów miesięcznie<br />
    [select* your-employees include_blank "0" "1-5" "6-20" "21-50" "51-100" "101-200" "powyżej 200"] </p>
</div>

<p>Dodatkowe informacje<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>[submit "Wyślij"]</p>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.kolumny{ width:100%; padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px; }
.polowa{ width:50%; display:inline-block; float:left; }
.polowa2{ width:50%; display:inline-block; }
```

But the problem is when I look at my page there is not two columns and in the source code I don't see any div called "polowa2".

Comment: i have copied your code and i can see two columns..then what is the issue?live link or screen shot where you are facing issue?

Comment: How do you include your form, from the editor with CF7 shortcode or from a template file?

Comment: `display:inline-block` is redundant if you have `float:left` specified. Try making your `.polowa` widths a bit smaller (48.5%).